# Your APK's version code needs to be higher than xxx phonegap

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-build

I am using phonegap to deploy my apps on Itunes and Google play.My config file looks like this

```
<widget 
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" 
xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0" 
id="com.crondale.tippnett" 
version="1.1.13">
<name>TippNett</name>
<description>TippNett er et system for å som bidrar til bedre massebalanse.    Systemet finner anlegg i nærheten med motsatt massebehov. Det bidrar til kortere kjørelengde og raskere anleggsutførsel. Du sparer penger, i tillegg til at miljøet blir spart for CO2 utslipp.</description>
<author href="http://www.crondale.com" email="support@crondale.com">Crondale</author>
<content src="index.html" />
<access origin="*" />

<preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
<preference name="windows-target-version" value="8.0" />
<preference name="windows-phone-target-version" value="8.1" />
<preference name="target-device" value="universal" />



 <platform name="android">
    <preference name="orientation" value="portrait" />
</platform>

<platform name="ios">
    <preference name="orientation" value="portrait" />
</platform>

<preference name="android-build-tool" value="gradle" />

<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" source="npm" version="1.0.0" />
<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" source="npm" version="1.0.1" />
<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-inappbrowser" source="npm" version="1.4.0" />
<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-network-information" source="npm" version="1.2.1" />

<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-geolocation" source="npm"/>

<icon src="icon.png" />
<icon src="res/icons/android/icon-36-ldpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="ldpi" />
<icon src="res/icons/android/icon-48-mdpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="mdpi" />
<icon src="res/icons/android/icon-72-hdpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="hdpi" />
<icon src="res/icons/android/icon-96-xhdpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="xhdpi" />
<icon src="res/icons/ios/icon-40.png" gap:platform="ios" width="40" height="40" /> 
<icon src="res/icons/ios/icon-40-2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="80" height="80" /> 
<icon src="res/icons/ios/icon-60.png" gap:platform="ios" width="60" height="60" /> 
<icon src="res/icons/ios/icon-60-2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="120" height="120" /> 
<!-- iPad --> 
<icon src="res/icons/ios/icon-76.png" gap:platform="ios" width="76" height="76" /> 
<icon src="res/icons/ios/icon-76-2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="152" height="152" /> 
....
</widget>
```

But when I try to upload the apk file on google developer console I get this error

```
Your APK's version code needs to be higher than 3718.
```

The current version of my app is 3718 and the version is 1.1.12.

Not the version is 1.1.13 but apparently apk I am uploading is also having the version 3718. How do I fix that? I didn't had to do that before.

Comment: Make that change in manifest file.

Comment: But I haven't touched the manifest file before when I used to upload my app. And also where in the manifest file?

Comment: in `platforms/android/AndroidManifest.xml`

Comment: I don't have any Manifest file there. I do have android.iml

Comment: Look for `android:versionCode="X"` that needs to be incremented.

Comment: I added it in Config.xml file

Comment: did that resolved your problem ?

Comment: Yes that did resolved my issue.

Comment: Post your answer and mark as answered :)

Answer (score 0):

Cordova v5 generates android:versionCode=XXXXXX in 6 digits but in latest Cordova v6 it is generating 5 digits versionCode and it will always be lower.  You need to add this in config.xml and update it manually so that it will generate exact what you want.

```
<widget id="com.xxx.xxx"  android-versionCode="300001" version="3.0.1">
```

Hope this will solve your problem.